The best design I could think up uses 2 PWM lines and a ground, how does this device do it with only 2 wires?
I have some strings of Christmas lights with various modes of operation, selectable at the control box. One mode lights up blue and green lights which, after a while, fades all the way out and then lights up with amber and red lights. One mode is just all four colors on full all the time. Other modes switch between the two pairs of colors without fading in or out wand produces a "chase" effect, and some modes are sequences of both fade and chase. Having a remedial knowledge of electronics, I thought I was pretty smart when I figured that the blue and green were LEDs wired in series and driven by a PWM output and the same was done for the amber and red LEDs on a second PWM line with both PWMs being sunk with a common ground connection.
When some of these Christmas lights stopped working properly I said I would look into it and boy was that an attitude adjustment to find that a string of 1000 LEDs was driven by a 30 volt DC power supply using only a TWO terminal connector!
So I figured 30 VDC would be good for about 16 LEDs in series, so I started where the 2 supply wires met the first light and became 3 wires like the old incandescent Christmas lights.
I followed the third wire and counted out 16 LEDs but the wire made no connection.  I kept counting and tracing and after 20 or 25 I couldn't understand why the third wire never met up with another connection point. By 50 I was freaking out but when I passed 100 I was considering Voodoo as an explanation!  I counted over and over, checking and rechecking, and after over 112 LEDs that third wire just kept on going.  I gave up before I saw it connect to anything. This was the circuit after over 112 LEDs:
So after the 112th LED it goes back down to just 2 wires. 1000 LEDs is very close to 9 parallel groups of 112 LEDs in series or 9 LEDs in series paralleled 112 times.  There's no way 30 VDC can drive 120 LEDs in series, and I cant imagine that some wire no thicker than 26 AWG or 24 AWG would be used for 112 parallel branches of LEDs (at 20 mA current to light an LED, 112 branches would draw 2.24 amps which might be possible but would leave zero margins for safety).
But let's just pretend that somehow all those LEDs would fit in the voltage and current constraints. There still is the problem of having two strings of lights (blue, green and amber, red) operate independently using only two wires!
This whole inquiry started because some of the lights only light up extremely dimly after being strung on the tree in the front yard after a year and would love to get them working again for the month of December. (They were not powered on from January till just a couple days ago.) What am I missing and can they be fixed?  (These are the lights in question which claim to be waterproof for outdoor use)
(As a side note, my Kill-A-Watt was also freaked out by these lights and insisted that they were running off 119.3 volts AC at 60.0 Hertz with a power factor of 1.00 (or 0.00 VA) which consumed 0.00 Amps of current at a rate of zero Watts!)
EDIT:  I swapped the control boxes between the bad string and some working ones.  All the control boxes/power supplies worked with the good strings.  The bad strings remained extremely dim regardless of which box they were plugged into.
The big question is what could be the source of the trouble, a bad connection? Or a component failure or partial failure of an LED? Or something else? Curious as to possible problems, not asking for clairvoyant virtual answer generation!  :)

The lights linked to in my question only use two wires for two channels, that's what felt like Voodoo to me.  I say in the title that I figured out how to do it with three wires.

There is a button on the LED controller box which cycles through 8 preset programs (modes).  Some are mellow as the lights slowly fade in and out.  Others are hectic as they blink rapidly a few times, first one channel and then the other, repeatedly.  Nice feature built in is that a long press on the button will activate a timer: 6 hours on then 18 hours off.

(While antiparallel LEDs are enough for fade(& ~ over) effects, I can't imagine they help for chase effects. BluTooth seems too complex/costly…)

BTW (as it's clearly not the case here) you can DC-couple power and AC-couple control signals onto one pair of wires, or even a single wire with the chassis as ground.

I'm not sure how your lights are configured, or what kind of power supply they are using, but it's quite easy to switch one set of lights on while the other is off, and vice versa, by controlling current direction:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You can cause both to illuminate simultaneously by rapidly switching current direction. During half the cycle current travels clockwise (red), and during the other half, current ravels counter-clockwise (blue):

simulate this circuit
You could also control relative brightness of each set of lights, by altering the ratio of durations of the clockwise and counter-clockwise periods. Don't forget that you don't have to have both clockwise and counter-clockwise periods; there can be periods of no current at all, permitting control of brightness of one set of lights, the other set of lights, or both simultaneously.
If the switching frequency is high enough, you don't see any flickering, just a consistent glow from both sets of LEDs.
You can add as many strings of LEDs as the current source can handle:

simulate this circuit
Diodes 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9 etc. will be lit simultaneously when current flows clockwise, and diodes 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12 etc. will be on when current is counter-clockwise.
These schematics may not be the whole picture. Depending on the power supply, which may be a current source or a voltage source, there may or may not be resistors present to balance currents. It's generally not a good idea to parallel-connect LEDS like this, causing them to all have the same voltage across them, unless they have built-in resistors, since even the slightest mismatch can cause current to be shared very unequally between them.
Different colour LEDs have different voltages across them. Red LEDs tend to operate on 1.7V or so, white and blue ones being closer to 3V or more, with green and amber somewhere in between. Therefore, you may find that strings of blue LEDs contain fewer LEDs than red, green or amber ones, so that all strings develop a similar total voltage with the same current through them. It's a balancing act, which might look something like this:

simulate this circuit
Your own wiring may be very different, but I have no doubt that they are wired to balance current and voltage for different groups of LEDs, while retaining the ability to control illumination of groups independently with current direction.
If it's not obvious which LEDs or sets of LEDs are problematic just from their brightness, troubleshooting is difficult. When LEDs are connected in series, if any one of them is bad, it will affect current flow in all the LEDs along that string. To fix those lights you'll probably need to identify and replace degraded ones, which you could do by measuring voltage across each one in turn. The ones with the wildly different voltage from the average are your main suspects. Parallel connected sets with one bad set in amongst them are more difficult to identify, because you will need to measure current in each branch, which would require cutting the current path and inserting an ammeter.

From a vague recollection having ripped apart a controller, similar lights run at either mains frequency or twice that, being rectified but not smoothed.  That works for mini incandescents at least, because the thermal mass of the filament provides smoothing (50-60Hz is detectable flicker in LEDs).  If you've got an oscilloscope, even a low frequency pocket one, you can look at the waveform.  An LED will work as a photodiode for wavelengths up to about the emission wavelength, so a spare red LED (in a clear package) can be used to study the drive pattern of any of these colours

There's an old puzzle that involves two mains-voltage lamps and two switches mounted to a board.
The bulbs are screwed into surface-mount ceramic or plastic sockets Like this:

The switches are ordinary mains wall switches mounted in surface mount enclosures like this:

A single conductor runs between the boxes and to each side of a mains plug, so the circuit appears to be like this (no wires are hidden in the board and it is truly a single conductor):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Yet each switch independently controls one of the bulbs. You can have neither bulb on, either one alone, or both.
The secret to the puzzle, as you might have guessed, is hidden small (eg. 1N4007) diodes in parallel with each device.

simulate this circuit
It's even easier with LEDs as they are their own diodes!
In this case, the LEDs are probably inverse-parallel rather than series, but the idea is similar- one polarity of current controls one set of lamps and the other polarity controls the other set. Switch back and forth fast enough and they all can appear to be on if desired.

That's really cool!  So if I understand correctly, say the positive, top half of AC will flow clockwise.  When SW2 is closed it allows LAMP1 to light up, bypasses LAMP2 by flowing through D2 and ignores SW1 because it always has D3 to flow through.  Then for the negative bottom half of the wave, SW1 would allow the bottom half of the AC wave to flow counter-clockwise and light up LAMP2.  So this would make the bulbs glow half as bright as normal?

@Darren Yes. SW1 controls lamp 2 (top lead +) and SW2 controls lamp 1 (top lead -). They glow less brightly than normal (70% RMS voltage but light is nonlinear w/voltage so it's not half), but it's not that obvious since we don't normally stare at bare incandescent light bulbs.

+1 for digging out that old trick! I loved it when we did it!

The LEDs could be in anti-parallel, so the two wires are either 0V/30V or alternatively 30V/0V, basically a H-bridge with single PWM channel.

So how do both strings stay on at the same time?
Wouldn't that be a situation like alternating current? I could picture this situation using a bipolar power supply, but then we're back to 3 wires.  Could you indulge me with a quick sketch of the schematic?

@Darren Let's try again, one set of LEDs light up at one colour with one polarity and another set with another polarity. The PWM is high frequency AC so the LEDs appear to be lit at the same time to your eyes but they alternate between colour sets tens of not hundreds of times per seconds, and most people can't see the flickering. The H bridge drives the chain with AC, alternating which wire gets positive and which negative.
